# Profinite completion motivation

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, motivation, profinite-groups

I have started galois theory recently, and curiosity quickly leads one to the subject of profinite groups. Although I have yet to be comfortable using these, I get what they are and we define them as we do, and when to expect them. 
I stumbled on a paper which tries to prove that the absolute galois group of $\mathbb{K}(t)$ for K algebraically closed of characteristic 0, is the "free profinite group of rank |K|". So after this I tried looking up what a free profinite group is, which lead me to the subject of profinite completion.

Although it is pretty abstract, I am just about able to understand the definition (barely). My question to help me with this difficulty is: 
What are some motivations for profinite completion? More specifically, why would one want to take a non profinite group and "turn it into" a profinite one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is an interesting question. I guess one way to think about this is that, very frequently, you want profinite analogues of abstract concepts/constructions and the profinite completion very often gives you a reasonable way to achieve this. For instance: take free products. The existence of the free profinite product of a finite number of profinite groups (say 
$G_1,\ldots, G_n$) involves taking a profinite completion of the abstract free product of the $G_i$. So, in other words, profinite completions are, by design, natural candidates for this sort of thing.